# How to load VAR's from ReadAllLines

Tags: c#

I have no idea how to load variables from the config that I create.

My config looks like:
test1 "2.0"
test2 "3.0"

that's my save code:

```
public static void Save(string filename)
{
    using (var st = System.IO.File.CreateText(filename))
    {
        foreach (var xx in testList.Values)
        {
            st.WriteLine("{0} \"{1}\"", xx.gName, xx.Value);
        }
    }
    Debug.Log("Saved: " + filename);
}
```

I need to assign a variable from the code to the variable that is in the config, any idea?

Comment: What's `testList`?

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel (saving/reading configuration information) why not use what already been built in the .Net framework?

Answer (score 1):

`File.ReadLines(filename)` would give you an `IEnumerable<string>` with each key/value pair, and then `string.split` would allow you to separate the key and value.

For example

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> Load(string filename)
{
  var config = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  foreach(string kvp in File.ReadLines(filename))
  {
    var parts = kvp.split(" ");
    config.Add(parts[0], parts[1].Replace("\"", ""););
  }
  return config;
}
```